# References appearing on chapter title page rather than starting on the next page

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, thesis

I am writing my doctoral thesis and have everything formatted as desired, apart from how the references are displayed.

When I insert the reference list:

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{Thesis.bib}
```

a new chapter is created with the title page "Chapter 7: References". However instead of printing the references on the next page they appear immediately below the chapter title and the footer layout is also different to the rest of the thesis (see image).

Is there a way to keep the references title page blank (apart from the title) and then print the reference list on the next page?

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}   
\newgeometry{hmargin={3cm,3cm}, vmargin={3cm,3cm}} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} % inserting figures
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
%\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter} %Font
\usepackage{caption} %figure captions
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont%
   \centering \fontsize{40}{50}% %change this size to your needs for the first line
    \bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{10pt}{%
    \vspace{1cm} \normalfont \huge %change this size to your needs for the second line
    }


\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\thepage}

\usepackage[textfont={it}]{caption}

\usepackage[numberedbib]{apacite}  %reference list
%\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}



\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}


%\raggedbottom

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{float}
%\setlength{\droptitle}{-8em} 
%\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5cm}

%\usepackage{microtype}


 \usepackage{tocloft}
 
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{6em}


\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
```

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please consider learning how to make a `MWE`. Also try the following:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[unnumberedbib]{apacite}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Doe05,
  author       = "Doe, J. and Other, X.",
  title        = "An interesting title",
  journal      = "A well regarded journal",
  volume       = "163",
  year         = "2005",
  pages        = "287--337",
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
This based on \cite{Doe05}.
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\end{document}
```

Is the option `unnumberedbib` what you were looking for?